# C - quicker way to shift an array without using int

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

as my assignment I'm writing a programm that's supposed to check char array with bool function and delete all chars in array that return true. The thing is that I'm not allowed to use indexing (nor any kind of int and libraries). I wrote a code that shifts my array but it is too slow.
I would be very grateful if anyone could point me to quicker way to do it.

```
bool filter(char* array, bool(*function)(char))
{
    if(array)
    {
        char *start = array;
        while(*(array) != 0)
        {
            if(function(*array) == false)
            {
                start++;
                array++;
            }
            else
            {
                while(*(array) != 0)
                {
                    *(array) = *(array + 1);
                    array++;
                }
                *(array) = 0;
                tablica = start;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: If I have a bool function that returns true for 'e' then you'll turn "steampower" into "st\0ampow\0r" or worse.  I'm guessing the answer should be "stampowr".  Then there's the fact that you don't seem to use start for anything but assign to the mystery variable tablica.

Comment: @GrahamBorland else belongs to the if inside the loop.

Comment: The indentation is bad but the braces are correct.

Comment: Sorry, was rushing too quick, and made some mistakes. Else half is supposed to give me an array {somewords000} as I'm printing this array `while(*(array) != 0)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to reshift the entire array every time a character is removed. Just keep a record of the current to and from positions when you are doing your copying. As long as there is no possibility of adding elements back into the array, you will not overwrite anything:

```
bool filter(char* array, bool(*function)(char)){
    if(array){
        char *start = array;
        while(*(array) != 0){
            if(function(*array) == false){
                *start = *array;
                start++;
            }
            array++
        }
        *start = '\0';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Mad Physicist Look great!  Minor question: why did you see the need to test `array` and not `function`?  I'd expect either both or neither to be tested (or asserted).

Comment: @chux You mean `if(array)`? I had to check if there actually is an array.

Comment: @user3072282 The query is more subtle.  _Many_ functions make assumptions about the non-NULL-ness of pointers like the `array` and assume it to be not NULL.  The answer does a test to insure its not NULL.  Its not _bad_ to test for NULL.  But if one is trying to make robust code that does not fail on a NULL `char` pointer, why _stop_ there and not also check if `function` (a function pointer) to see if it is NULL.

Comment: What's the point of `start`? It has the filtered string but it's not returned.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey, `start` is the place we copy the characters that are not deleted to. This will be behind `array` once we encounter deleted characters. The name `start` is not well chosen under the circumstances, but I went with the author's original code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your professor is pushing you toward using pointers instead of indexes. Try this:

```
//UNTESTED
void filter(char* array, bool(*function)(char)) {
  char *src;
  char *dest;
  char c;

  src = dest = array;

  while(c = *src++) {
    if (!function(c))
      *dest++ = c;
  }
  *dest = 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like real C

Answer (score 0):

K&R style:

```
void filter(char *array, bool(*function)(char))
{
    char *dst;
    if(!array) return;

    for (dst=array; *dst = *array++; ) {
        if (function(*dst)) continue;
        dst++;
    }
}
```